# Git repository authorization/access control as easy as with Subversion?

Tags: git, apache, svn, authorization, access-control

Up until now we have used solely Subversion as our SCM system in the following way:

- Served via HTTPS only
- Authentication performed by Apache Webserver (`$REMOTE_USER` is available), no anonymous access
- WebSVN for browsing
- Authorization is performed by `AuthzSVNAccessFile`

The `AuthzSVNAccessFile` contains ro/rw permissions for all users and repos. No path-based, but blanked for the entire repo or not. The tooling is perfectly integrated into Subversion and WebSVN. Single, idiotproof, easy-to-setup configuration.

Now, we'd like to have the same approach for Git too:

- Served via HTTPS only
- Authentication performed by Apache Webserver (`$REMOTE_USER` is available), no anonymous access
- gitweb for browsing
- Authorization is performed by ???

The gap is ???. As far as I can see, there is no official Git tooling for this. There has never been the same motivation as with Subversion, namely public repos on the Internet. No need for complex access control. Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22701195/696632), Gitolite seems to be the filling third-party gap. Infact, I read the documentation and it seems to be overly complex compared to the Subversion `AuthzSVNAccessFile` approach.

Am I missing something? Is Gitolite the way to go? Are there any reasonable alternative for a single permissions configuration?

Note: It has to work with repo access (Git Bash, Git on Un*x, TortoiseGit) as well as with gitweb in one go. I do not intend to use SSH paired with ACLs or roll an entire GitLab instance or alike. Must run on FreeBSD, preferrably through ports.

Comment: Gitolite is the way to go. I personally hate it, because it *is* complicated, but all that complication is there for some good reasons (including the fancy remote admin using Gitolite to control access to the admin rules!).

Comment: @torek. You might want to turn that into an answer. I read about the admin repo via SSH. I'd rather login via SSH as root and edit a config file. The entire approach seems overdesigned to me or it is simply in the nature of Git that is cannot be solved easier.

Comment: I only set up Gitolite once, after which other people than me used it, so I'm not as familiar with it as I'd like to make it a real answer. They seemed happy with it though.

Comment: Forget about shitty Git|Gitolite nightmare and use Mercurial with [ACL Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/AclExtension#Configuration)?!

Comment: @LazyBadger. As I have written, no SSH fiddling. HTTP only. This extension seems to be available for `hg-ssh` only.

Comment: @Michael-O - ""It's *recommended* that this extension is used with hg-ssh" (**not required**), AFAICS it's protocol-independent, because use hooks (which doesn't correlate to access-method)

Comment: @LazyBadger thanks. I get quite the feeling that most of those solutions are plumbered to Git/Mercurial instead been tightly integrated by default.